# Source code: can't find definition of "SSLv2_method()" function

Tags: openssl

- SSLv2_method()
- SSLv23_method()
- SSLv3_method()
- TLSv1_method()
- DTLSv1_method()

They are only mentioned in ssl/ssl.h as function prototypes, 
but they don't have actual function definition in the OpenSSL source code, even using ctag or find/grep.

What's the exact reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They are only mentioned in ssl/ssl.h as function prototypes, but they don't have actual function definition in the OpenSSL source code, even using ctag or find/grep.
>
> What's the exact reason?

They are macros that unwind into mostly function pointers. The functions that operate on them use the same "base" structure, and just get the pointers from the unwound macros. So the difference between the `SSLv2_method`, `SSLv3_method`, etc is essentially pointers specified in the macro.

For an analysis of how to untangle them, see [SSL Context Methods - Generic vs Server/Client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23875325/608639). (His question was different enough that your question was not a duplicate ;)